# Repeat row based on the number in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6470e/12)

I need to repeat each barcode of the article based on the quantity of this article in the table Stock.

This is source data:

```
| BarCode | quantity |
|---------|----------|
| 5142589 |        7 |
|  123454 |        5 |
| 1111145 |        3 |
```

I want result that looks like this:

```
Barcode
-------
5142589
5142589
5142589
5142589
5142589
5142589
5142589
123454
123454
123454
123454
123454
1111145
1111145
1111145
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I edited the expected result in the question to match the sample data from the Fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this by a simple recursive **CTE**.

```
 WITH cte
    AS
    (
      SELECT IdArticle,1 AS rn FROM TABLE_STOCK
      UNION ALL
      SELECT t.IdArticle,rn+1 AS rn
      FROM cte c 
        INNER JOIN TABLE_STOCK t ON t.IdArticle = c.IdArticle and rn<t.QUANTITY
    )

    SELECT t.BarCode,TS.QUANTITY
     FROM cte c 
        INNER JOIN TABLE_BARCODE t ON t.IdArticle = c.IdArticle 
        INNER JOIN TABLE_STOCK TS ON TS.IdArticle = C.IdArticle
    ORDER BY t.IdArticle
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6470e/1)

Comment: Thank you for your help, Its help me very much :-D

Answer (score 5):

You can use [table of numbers](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1). Either permanent, or generated on the fly.

Query below uses `CTE` to generate up to 1000 numbers. Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6470e/14/0).

```
WITH 
e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
) -- 10
,e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b) -- 10*10
,e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e2) -- 10*100
,CTE_Numbers
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) AS Number
    FROM e3
)
SELECT b.BarCode, s.quantity
FROM 
  TABLE_BARCODE b
  INNER JOIN TABLE_STOCK s ON b.IdArticle = s.IdArticle
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT TOP(s.quantity) CTE_Numbers.Number
    FROM CTE_Numbers
    ORDER BY CTE_Numbers.Number      
  ) AS CA
```

**Results:**

```
| BarCode | quantity |
|---------|----------|
| 5142589 |        7 |
| 5142589 |        7 |
| 5142589 |        7 |
| 5142589 |        7 |
| 5142589 |        7 |
| 5142589 |        7 |
| 5142589 |        7 |
|  123454 |        5 |
|  123454 |        5 |
|  123454 |        5 |
|  123454 |        5 |
|  123454 |        5 |
| 1111145 |        3 |
| 1111145 |        3 |
| 1111145 |        3 |
```

Comment: You were faster, great answer ;) I wanted to use `VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))` instead of `UNION ALL` [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6470e/35/0)

Answer (score 2):

Simplified and improved version of Vladmir's answer:

```
DECLARE @t table(BarCode int, quantity int)
INSERT @t values(5142589, 7),(123454, 5),(1111145,3)

;WITH 
e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
) -- 10
,e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b) -- 10*10
,e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e2 CROSS JOIN e2 ex) -- 100*100
SELECT BarCode
FROM @t t
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT top(t.quantity) null dummy 
  FROM e3
) x
```

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. In this case we don't need actual numbers, we need only rows. I normally use permanent table of numbers, not CTE, so missed that.